# Storing form data in a variable angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

i am having play around with angular and i am trying to store a name entry to a variable. When you type your name in and click next i want to take the data from the input field and store that into a variable. Can this be done and if so whats the best way to go about this? iv provided a non working example below

HTML:

```
 <button class="button" ng-click="next()"> Next</button>
     <form>
      <label class="item">
       <input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name"></input>
      </label>
     </form>
    <h3 style="color:black">{{name}}</h3>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.next = function() {
    var nameresult = $scope.name;
  };
```

Comment: Yes you can do it..and your code should work? `nameresult` will be local to the `next` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're binding, you are actively writing to a variable in the model of the controller. If you want it to be a specific object you can define it on the scope (`$scope.myObject`) and bind to that (`ng-model="myObject.Value"`).

See this plunker for example: [plink plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YX01famHYVKlF9AytEF1?p=preview)